# How to convert a 3D model to .h file to be imported in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d

I need to import a model into my iPhone app. I see it should be exproted as .h file, but I need to tool to form this .h file having model's vertices, normals .. and all model's data. I read this article of how to add a script to blender, but I failed to find the path to add th obj.py script in blender 2.58. As I open blender.app package I find the following folders:
Contents=>(MacOS(2.57, blender), Resources) and I could not find the path that article mentioned.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html

Anyone knows how to create a .h file for a model even if without using blender?

Comment: If you look at the script you'll see that it's not all that difficult to interpret and write something similar yourself. Either for another modeling package or something that directly goes from .obj to a header file. It just writes out some arrays and OpenGL code. If your problem is more related to Blender than the actual programming, you might be better of by asking the Blender community directly on one of the forums or even IRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could make a small desktop application that generates for the .h files right away. Here is the main class for an OBJ loader I wrote for Android.

Kindly note that I was experimenting with the code, so it is not clean, but it works perfectly!

You could port that code to desktop, then in the fillInBuffers() function, you start writing the arrays into a file.

You gonna have to call glDrawElements btw. I hope that this will help ;)

**EDIT:** forgot to say that Vector3D is a simple class that hold that I made to hold the X,Y and Z values, and Face class holds arrays of UVWs, Vertices, and vertex normals

```
public class Model {

    // Constants
    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int SHORT_SIZE_BYTES = 2;

    private FloatBuffer _vb;
    private FloatBuffer _nb;
    private ShortBuffer _ib;
    private FloatBuffer _tcb;

    private short[] indices;

    private float[] tempV;
    private float[] tempVt;
    private float[] tempVn;

    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertices;
    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertexTexture;
    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertexNormal;
    private ArrayList<Face> faces;
    private int vertexCount;

    private ArrayList<GroupObject> groupObjects;

    //Android Stuff!
    private Context context;
    private int modelID;

    public Model(int modelID, Context activity)
    {
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.vertexTexture = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.vertexNormal = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        this.groupObjects = new ArrayList<GroupObject>();

        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.context = activity;

        loadFile();
    }

    private int loadFile()
    {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(modelID);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            loadOBJ(in);
            Log.d("LOADING FILE", "FILE LOADED SUCESSFULLY====================");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private void loadOBJ(BufferedReader in) throws IOException
    {
        Log.d("LOADING FILE", "STARTING!====================");
        GroupObject defaultObject = new GroupObject();
        GroupObject currentObject = defaultObject;

        this.groupObjects.add(defaultObject);

        String Line;            // Stores ever line we read!
        String[] Blocks;        // Stores string fragments after the split!!
        String CommandBlock;    // Stores Command Blocks such as: v, vt, vn, g, etc...

        while((Line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Blocks = Line.split(" ");
            CommandBlock = Blocks[0];

//          Log.d("COMMAND BLOCK" , "---------- " + CommandBlock + " ----------");

            if(CommandBlock.equals("g"))
            {
                if(Blocks[1] == "default")
                    currentObject = defaultObject;
                else
                {
                    GroupObject groupObject = new GroupObject();
                    groupObject.setObjectName(Blocks[1]);
                    currentObject = groupObject;
                    groupObjects.add(groupObject);
                }
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("v"))
            {
                Vector3D vertex = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertices.add(vertex);
//              Log.d("VERTEX DATA", " " + vertex.getX() + ", " + vertex.getY() + ", " + vertex.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("vt"))
            {
                Vector3D vertexTex = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), 0.0f);
                this.vertexTexture.add(vertexTex);
//              Log.d("TEXTURE DATA", " " + vertexTex.getX() + ", " + vertexTex.getY() + ", " + vertexTex.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("vn"))
            {
                Vector3D vertexNorm = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertexNormal.add(vertexNorm);
//              Log.d("NORMAL DATA", " " + vertexNorm.getX() + ", " + vertexNorm.getY() + ", " + vertexNorm.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("f"))
            {
                Face face = new Face();
                faces.add(face);

                String[] faceParams;

                for(int i = 1; i < Blocks.length ; i++)
                {               
                    faceParams = Blocks[i].split("/");

                    face.getVertices().add(this.vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[0]) - 1));                 

                    if(faceParams[1] == ""){}
                    else
                    {
                        face.getUvws().add(this.vertexTexture.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[1]) - 1));
                        face.getNormals().add(this.vertexNormal.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[2]) - 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//      fillInBuffers();
        fillInBuffersWithNormals();

        Log.d("OBJ OBJECT DATA", "V = " + vertices.size() + " VN = " + vertexTexture.size() + " VT = " + vertexNormal.size());

    }

    private void fillInBuffers() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for(int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++)
        {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9]     = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();
            tempVt[i * 6]     = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();
            indices[i * 3]     = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length
                * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length
                * SHORT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    private void fillInBuffersWithNormals() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        tempVn = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for(int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++)
        {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9]     = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();

            tempVn[i * 9]     = face.getNormals().get(0).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 1] = face.getNormals().get(0).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 2] = face.getNormals().get(0).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 3] = face.getNormals().get(1).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 4] = face.getNormals().get(1).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 5] = face.getNormals().get(1).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 6] = face.getNormals().get(2).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 7] = face.getNormals().get(2).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 8] = face.getNormals().get(2).getZ();

            tempVt[i * 6]     = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();

            indices[i * 3]     = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length
                * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _nb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVn.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _nb.put(tempVn);
        _nb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length
                * SHORT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    public FloatBuffer getVertices()
    {
        return _vb;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getTexCoords()
    {
        return _tcb;
    }

    public ShortBuffer getIndices()
    {
        return _ib;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getNormals() {
        return _nb;
    }
}
```

Comment: has anyone wrote an any iOS equivalent?